# Is there a way to refresh the Pantheon-Files "Entire-Network"

Tags: pantheon-files, samba

If I leave my home and go to my friend's the "Entire-Network" will continue to show my samba shares from home, I've tried killing Files and pantheon-files-daemon, but it still persists. Is there a way to refresh it?

I'm using Freya, also wondering if this persists in Loki?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try killing the gvfs process.  It will automatically restart when needed.  I haven't had a chance to test this but hopefully it will work.  You could also try disabling and re-enabling networking.

Files just shows whatever gvfs gives to it so it is not really a bug in Files as such (unless other file managers do not suffer from the problem).